Delphi 12. Выделенный блок (обычное выделение мышью в IDE ) не очищается целиком на Del / BackSpace
Возникла уже порядком надоевшая проблема, при которой выделенный блок (обычное выделение мышью или клавишами) в редакторе кода IDE DELPHI — не удаляется (точнее говоря, удаляется только 1 символ из этого блока), а не целиком, как это всегда и везде работает в windows/
Иногда спасал перезапуск IDE. Теперь вот столкнулся с тем, что даже перезагрузка операционной системы и запуска любого (хоть даже чистого проекта) приводит к тому же багу.. Возможно конечно это и фича.. но подскажите пожалуйста, как ее снять, все перепробовал.. Может сброс какой-то в настройках Delphi 12 (также замечал периодически это поведение и в более ранних версиях, но уж перезапуск IDE точно всегда работал)

Похожая проблема уже много лет - после выделения вертикального блока текста (с помощью Alt). Решается тем, что выделяю часть строки курсором и два раза жму Insert (переключая режим Insert/Overwrite/Insert). Попробуйте.

Спасибо! Обязательно опробую, именно такую комбинацию

Проверьте в настройках Tools > Options > User Interface > Editor Options галочку "Overwrite blocks"

Да, именно оно, спасибо ! Тоже вчера все облазил в настройках и случайно нашел это... повторное переключение сразу решает сей трабл.
Все-же непонятно, отчего она сбивается, эта подстройка, помнится еще c неближних времен сей баг периодически всплывает, не починят ))

Похоже точно так же сбивается настройка "Whole words" в поиске. Всегда её снимаю, и часто рандомно она опять проставляется.

Похожая проблема уже много лет - после выделения вертикального блока текста (с помощью Alt). Решается тем, что выделяю часть строки курсором и два раза жму Insert (переключая режим Insert/Overwrite/Insert).
Также проверьте в настройках Tools > Options > User Interface > Editor Options галочку "Overwrite blocks"

Зачем ответ делать общим?

@Chaos_Sower затем что он состоит из моего ответа в комментариях и ответа в комментариях Германа Борисова. Мне показалось уместным сделать такой ответ из них.

Мне не кажется это уместным — вы могли написать "Как сказал @Герман Борисов...". Общими следует делать ответы, которые активно редактируются для дополнения ответа знаниями участников. В вашем случае это к данной ситуации не относится. Вот про общие ответы: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki и вот: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2436

Право ваше, но мне не кажется, что этот ответ попадает под категорию общий ¯_(ツ)_/¯

@Chaos_Sower вы конечно можете активно отредактировать ответ, но в данном случае аттрибуция добавит больше шума, чем принесет пользы. Общими ответы делаются по нескольким причинам, в т.ч. для переноса и объединения чужих комментариев в ответ (на Мете был вопрос про это, можете поискать).

@Kromster Да, тоже заметил. Походу нас таких немного, кто это замечает, т.к Делфи (вопреки всей своей истинной мощи актуальной и поныне), потихоньку канет в лету... (
       * По мне так оно из категории "Если свет в глазу преломлялся бы немного иначе и трава была бы синяя, то жизнь была-бы совершенно другая...". Но господину Chaos_Sower виднее конечно, может оно действительно важно ))

